# Group results based upon order when the date values are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a base table in a CTE that is then used to derive types based upon business rules to then validate output in a fact table. 
However a new rule has been added to the fact table, that when records have the same create date, then the order of priority is as follows:

- Entrytypeid = 5 and routeId = ‘Phone’ then 1
- Entrytypeid in (2,3,4,5)  then 2
- All other Entrytypeid then 3

My query below will produce the base table which is as follows and then I the get interaction types:

```
with CTE_TypeBase as
(

     SELECT 

    th.IncidentId,
    CurrIncidentStatus = inc.incidentstatusid,
    isnull(th.StaffId,-1) as CurrStaffId,
    CurrEntryTypeID  = th.EntryTypeID ,
    CurrDateCreated = th.DateCreated,
    PrevEntryTypeID = lag(th.EntryTypeID , 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY                  th.IncidentId ORDER BY th.DateCreated asc),
    PrevDateCreated = lag(th.DateCreated, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY th.IncidentId ORDER BY th.DateCreated asc),
    PrevID Id = lag(th.ID Id, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY th.IncidentId ORDER BY th.DateCreated asc),
    PrevStaffId = isnull(lag(th.StaffId, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY th.IncidentId ORDER BY th.DateCreated asc),-1),
    PrevIncidentStatus = lag(inc.IncidentStatusId, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY th.IncidentId ORDER BY th.DateCreated asc),
    CurrID Id = th.ID Id,
    PrecedenceOrder = DENSE_RANK() over (partition by th.DateCreated order by th.DateCreated, th.EntryTypeID  asc),
    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY th.IncidentId ORDER BY th.DateCreated asc)


FROM stage.ID  th
left join [stage].[Incident] inc on inc.IncidentId = th.IncidentId
WHERE th.EntryTypeID  in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
  and th.incidentid = 150000)
```

Selected Output:

```
  IncidentId    CurrEntryTypeId CurrDateCreated    PrevEntryTypeID  PrevDateCreated     PrevId  CurrId  PrecedenceOrder    RowNumber
  150000        3               22/08/2013 13:37    0                  01/01/1900 00:00 0       238475  1                   1
  150000        6               22/08/2013 13:37    3              22/08/2013 13:37 238475  238476  2                   2
  150000        3               22/08/2013 13:58    6               22/08/2013 13:37    238476  239035  1                   3
  150000        2               22/08/2013 18:50    3                 22/08/2013 13:58  239035  248796  1                   4
```

Now I managed to use dense_rank to identify which records follow the order of priority, I then need to identify those records that fall within the priority.

I thought about adding another CTE and then referencing CTE_TypeBase that would then use a case to identify any records with precedenceOrder > 1 then set to 1. 
But that will only identify only 1 record, I need to be able to select records with the same create date and apply the same logic.

So I need to get a output as follows, ignore the other values and only return values that are affected:

```
  IncidentId    CurrEntryTypeId CurrDateCreated    CurrId   PrecedenceOrder    RowNumber
  150000        3               22/08/2013 13:37   238475   1                   1
  150000        6               22/08/2013 13:37   238476   2                   2
```

Comment: `LAG(..., 1, 0)` supplies a default (the `0`), so the `ISNULL` is unnecessary.  Your precedence is wrong (doesn't take `routeId` into account), and doesn't condense the multiple `EntryTypeId`s; you also don't need to order by `DateCreated` in that window (because of the partitioning).  Why are you removing some of the records?